# Function composition demonstrate range is countable

Tags: functions

It seems intuitive to me but I have a hard time proving it (specially in math language) can anyone help?

given the sets $X,Z \neq \emptyset$ and a countable set $Y$

considering $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $h: Y \rightarrow Z$ so that $ h \circ f (X) = Z$

Demonstrate that $Z$ is also countable.

Definition for Y countable: there is a surjective function $g: \mathbb N \rightarrow Y$

I believe I can infer from this that $h$ is injective and $f$ is surjective, however that still does not tell me that $h$ is surjective, making $Z$ countable as well...

what am I missing?

Comment: What is your definition of countable? Can you apply it to $Y$? Can you "transfer" that fact to $Z$?

Comment: The cardinality of $Z$ is smaller than the cardinality of $Y$ if there is an injection from $Z$ to $Y$. You can use the axiom of choice and $h$ to create such an injection.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I edited the post to include the definition, and added some thoughts.

Comment: @FlorisClaassens there are no know injections, so all needs to be calculated...

Comment: @Tiago Nunes, I've worked out the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $z\in Z$ we define the set $h^{-1}(z)=\{y\in Y:h(y)=z\}$. As $Z=h(f(X))\subset h(Y)\subset Z$, we find that $h$ is surjective, thus we can create a map $k:Z\rightarrow Y$ by using the axiom of choice to pick $k(z)\in h^{-1}(z)$ for all $z$.

Finally note that since $h$ is a map for all $z_{1},z_{2}\in Z$ we have $h^{-1}(z_{1})\cap h^{-1}(z_{2})=\emptyset$, hence $k$ is injective. It follows that $|Z|\leq|Y|$ so $Z$ is countable.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: I am not following why $ h(f(X)) \subset h(Y)=Z$ tells us that h is surjective and couldn't $h(f(x)) \subseteq h(Y)$ ?

Comment: I use $\subset$ as $\subseteq$, and $\subsetneq$ for what you probably who denote as $\subset$. I changed the answer a little bit to make clearer why $h$ is surjective.

Comment: thank you for the clarification Floris, you rock :-)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $X$ is countable means there exists a **surjective** mapping $\lambda:\mathbb{N}\to X$. Then it is easy to see that the function $\lambda\cdot f:\mathbb{N}\to f(X)$ is also surjective. So $f(X)$ is also countable. Repeating this argument for $gf(X)=Z$, we complete the proof.